# drupal menu item which is not a link

Tags: php, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I am trying to use [special menu items](http://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items) to make certain menu item(s) not a link.  There are some [issues](http://drupal.org/node/507758) with this module, and I am unable to do so.  Currently, I am testing it with the garland theme.  Although this seems like a basic feature, I am finding it difficult to accomplish this task.  Do you have any suggestions.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

http://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items works.